How to let two qemu instances access each other under the same network? The host is Windows 11
The first instance is:
.\qemu-system-x86_64.exe -cpu IvyBridge -smp 4 -m 4096 -nic user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:10022-:22 D:\vm1.qcow2 -accel whpx

So the network backend is user mode network of qemu, then how to create the second instance so that they can share the same user mode network? That is, the second IP should be 10.0.2.16.

It seems that there's this -netdev socket. Not really sure how it works though. You may try to just "listen and connect" and see whether it automagically gives you a shared user mode network. (The lines there might be wrong, as in, you probably need to specify an IP such as 127.0.0.1 along with the port to "connect", as shown in the example in the man page.)

I tried socket, but no luck. It's reasonable if two instances could use the same user mode network, i.e. use the same DHCP server to retrieve the IP address and use the same gateway to access the Internet.
